# ASP.net Oracle DataReader in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, odp.net

I have an `ASP.net` appication in which it uses an `ODP.net` database connection. I have extracted the database handler into a `dll file` in order to extend its flexibility.

An error pops up occasionaly saying as follows:

```
Error   1   Assembly 'DatabaseConnection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' which has a higher version than referenced assembly
'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'    c:\Documents and Settings\Visual Studio 
2010\Projects\DatabaseConnection\bin\Debug\DatabaseConnection.dll
```

Last time it happend, the error faded away automatically alone.

What is the reason for such error?

Comment: As the message says: your DatabaseConnection dll is using ODAC Version 4.112.2.0, your project referencing the DatabaseConnection version 2.112.2.0. Maybe you installed one/both versions to the GAC?

Answer (score 0):

From the error look at the version number, your dll is expecting `Oracle.DataAccess` of  **Version=4.112.2.0** and i believe maybe in your GAC or bin you have a lower version **2.112.2.0**.

Try to get the required version and this should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Also - if you are using .Net 4.0 - you must use the 4.x assembly to be supported by Oracle.